# Yii2 - WHERE IN with active record

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to make WHERE IN condition with active record? I am going through documentation, but I can't find this case. I need to perform this query and return count value.

This is the method I am using for now:

```
public function static findProductsOnSale($ids)
    {
        return $this->find()->where(['product_id' => $ids])->count();
    }
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As [documentation about where()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail) says:

> ['id' => [1, 2, 3], 'status' => 2] generates (id IN (1, 2, 3)) AND (status = 2)

so your method should be correct. 
If you want to use *IN* then your code should look like this:

```
public function static findProductsOnSale($ids)
{
    return $this->find()->where(['in', 'product_id', $ids])->count();
}
```